# Using c#, how can I overload all operators at once?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, conversion-operator

I have a struct like this.

```
public struct Money
{
    private readonly decimal _quantity;

    private Money(decimal qty)
    {
        _quantity = Math.Round(qty, 2);
    }

    public static implicit operator Money(decimal dec)
    {
        return new Money(dec);
    }
}
```

For `Money` do I have to overload all operators +, -, <, <=, >, >=, ==, !=, etc.? Or is there a way to accept all operators of `decimal` for `Money` as well? As you see `Money` has only one field which is `_quantity`. I want that all operators asked for `Money` should return as if it is asked for _quantity.

Maybe overloading below implicit conversion operator will solve the problem.

```
public static implicit operator decimal(Money money)
{
    return money._quantity;
}
```

I am creating `Money` struct, because I do not want to use `decimal` in my entire project. Compiler should force me to use `Money` instead of `decimal`. If I use above conversion operator implicitly, it wil contradict the reason behind creating this struct. 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You *have to* implement *all* the operators *separately*, but you can *simplify* the process
by inmplementing `static Compare` method (in order to emulate `<=>` operator which is *not supported* by C#):

```
public struct Money: IComparble<Money> {
  private readonly decimal _quantity;

  ...

  // C# doesn't have <=> operator, alas...
  public static int Compare(Money left, Money right) {
    if (left._quantity < right._quantity)
      return -1;
    else if (left._quantity > right._quantity)
      return 1;
    else 
      return 0;
  }

  public static Boolean operator == (Money left, Money right) {
    return Compare(left, right) == 0;
  }

  public static Boolean operator != (Money left, Money right) {
    return Compare(left, right) != 0;
  }

  public static Boolean operator > (Money left, Money right) {
    return Compare(left, right) > 0;
  }

  public static Boolean operator < (Money left, Money right) {
    return Compare(left, right) < 0;
  } 

  public static Boolean operator >= (Money left, Money right) {
    return Compare(left, right) >= 0;
  }

  public static Boolean operator <= (Money left, Money right) {
    return Compare(left, right) <= 0;
  } 

  public int CompareTo(Money other) {
    return Compare(this, other);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dmitry. But my operator overload methods already have the structure `return left._quantity<operator>right._quantity`. If c# have supported generic operators as well as generic types, then my question would have an answer.

Comment: @serdar: Yes, the absence of "<=>" operator (which can combine all the comparisons) and Numeric type (for implementing arithmetics) is sometimes annoying.